# Is it possible to restrict the options available in an HTML5 date input?

Tags: html, date

I'm building a mobile web site that has a date input in a form.

I want to use the HTML 5 `<input type="date">` for iPhone users, and all other users will just get a `<select>`.

The thing is, I want to restrict users to only picking dates within the next 30 days. I've got my JS working to do this with the `<select>` - is there a way of entering a range for the `<input>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The min and max attributes will do this for you

Comment: I'd need to use JS to set the ranges in these attributes but that's fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not with HTML5 purely. But there are **[tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/dateinput/)** to do the job for you.